# Power BI :: No conditional formatting on the bar color

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I was having a look at this video at minute [2:00](https://youtu.be/Eop1HsBjWwo?si=4YWnd_utTDRuL7Gg&t=120) and I see that the Stacked bar chart visual has the option of change the color of the bar dynamically.

This is not the case for me:

What is wrong with my Stacked bar chart?

[image]

I'm running on the latest version of Power BI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Bars Drop Down, Select All for Categories. The f(x) should be there.